# can I implement Holo theme and keep the old theme to support older devices?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement the holo theme for my app, so far so good...
but the app didn't work on older devices pre 3.0

so I made a custom theme, in values dir and values-v11 dir to make android switch to the correct one on runtime...

I also set the target sdk level to 7 to support android 2.1

now the holo theme isn't recognized

Am I aiming for something impossible?

**What I want is pre 3.0 devices to use the default android theme
and everything that supports holo to use holo theme.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" />
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing now, but the problem is I have to set an sdk for the project right? setting it to android 3.0 won't let that app run on 2.1 and setting it to 2.1 says that Theme.Holo is undefined? am I missing something?

Comment: in manifest sir? `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />`

Comment: Indeed, like @yolapop said. However it is recommended that you use the highest targetSdkVersion as possible (16 or 17).

Comment: allready have that in the manifest put it before the application tag, still cant run it on 2.1(emulator) if I go to project settings, and set the target sdk to 3.0 or higher... setting it to 2.1 still says no holo...

Comment: How about your project build target? (In project settings)

Comment: sorry my last comment wasn't formulated correctly by "target sdk" I mean"project build target", setting it to 3.0 won't run the app on older devices setting it to 2.1 says holo is undefined

Comment: Setting the project build target won't restrict your app to be ran on older devices. Only the minimum sdk in the manifest will do that.

Comment: turns out only the launcher in eclipse doesn't look at the minimum sdk in the manifest... so I have to switch the target sdk when testing, but it works like a charm when deployed! thanks!